# Should typescript @types packages version match their non types packages?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

Do @types use the same versioning as the untyped package?

`npm i bluebird @types/bluebird -S` gives me

```
"@types/bluebird": "^3.5.0",
"bluebird": "^3.5.0",
```

Seems pretty reasonable.

`npm i request @types/request -S` gives me

```
"@types/request": "0.0.41",
"request": "^2.81.0",
```

Now this scares me a bit. 
Does this mean that we only have request types for request version 0.0.41?

Comment: don't worry `@types/request` and `request` are two separated modules, and the last update for `@types/request` was 7 days ago , see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/request

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should typescript @types packages version match their non types packages?

No. TypeScript types for JS packages is best effort and depends on

- official js documentation (commonly lacking)
- Community interest in the package

So version mismatches are fine as long as you are aware of their *best effort* nature.