# Versioning for typescript type definitions (@types/)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-definition

Is there any documentation on how the versions of the base packages relate to the ones from [@types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) to be used in Typescript?

I saw that they are not 1:1 and f.eg. for react 15.4.2 what @types/react should I use?

Answer (score 1):

[There is open issue about that on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/7719). So far, [no one was able to do anything about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768836/should-typescript-types-packages-version-match-their-non-types-packages).

> I saw that they are not 1:1 and f.eg. for react 15.4.2 what @types/react should I use?

The only way to find version of typings comatible withr specific version of a library is by trial and error.

From my experience, if you use the latest version of a lilbrary, specifying `*` as a version for typings in `package.json` works most of the time.