# How to know that typescript type definitions in @types match the actual package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I have been using typescript for a little while in node.js projects. I understand that for many npm packages there is separate @types package for typescript type definitions.

My question is: how can I know that the @types package is up to date with the latest version of the actual package when they are maintained separately?

For example there is npm package [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) with no typescript definitions and then a separate type definition package [@types/better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/better-sqlite3). How user of the package can know that types match the current version of the package?

In this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42771216/13277644) it is said that "TypeScript types for JS packages is best effort and depends on Community interest in the package". This sounds a bit scary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to relate a version of @types package to the versions of the associated JS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071705/how-to-relate-a-version-of-types-package-to-the-versions-of-the-associated-js-p)

Answer (score 1):

The types package shouldn't be maintained separately. The author of the package should be listing the corresponding types package as a `dependency` which means the correct version of the typing should come along when you install the top-level package.

REF: https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81

Edit: As pointed out in the comments by @Gwydion, there are some packages that are community maintained outside of the originating package. A good example is:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3

It would seem *likely* the following package is the correct types package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/better-sqlite3

But, it's not necessarily obvious either. It would be nice to have to signal to verify that this is the correct package.

Here is what I did:

1. I visited the originating npm package page, taking note of the repository URL which is: https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3
2. I visited the repository URL of the type package, which is: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/better-sqlite3 (this URL was listed on the type package's npm page under Details)
3. Open the `index.d.ts` file located there. At the top it lists: `Project: https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3`.

NOTE: https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3 redirects to https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3 which matches what we found in #1 above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I understand that many npm packages include typescript definitions.

But I assumed that if package does not contain definitions then for some packages there are community maintained @types definition packages available that need to be installed separately. And was wondering, how user can be sure that these 2 match.

Maybe there is something fundamental about this I am getting wrong.

Comment: For example there is package https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3. There is no types as dependency in the package.json. But you can find a separate type definition package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/better-sqlite3 Just wondering how user can be sure that the package and types-package match?

Comment: @Gwydion, thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer as such. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the package developers maintain the definitions themselves, there's no `@types`, `d.ts`s are just building in package distro
2. If there's `@types`, you may check the last update date of both packages (`@types` have `Last updated` in readme), the `@types` probably was correct at the time when it was last updated.
3. If the `@types` is outdated, you may update if yourself and even publish on `@types`, that's what "TypeScript types for JS packages is best effort and depends on Community interest in the package" means